# What locations should I use in a firebase project as a developer in EU

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm about to start a new firebase project living in EU. I want to use Firestore and Cloud functions, but they are not to find in the same locations.

Cloud functions: 
europe-west1 (Belgium)

Firestore:
europe-west2 (London)
europe-west3 (Frankfurt)
europe-west6 (Zürich)

Could I use different locations, or is the performance too bad?
Or should I rather use a location in USA with both?

Comment: It's really hard to say without knowing exactly what your code is going to do.  I suggest doing some benchmarks of your use cases to see how it actually works out.

Comment: For a production app, I use Cloud functions in europe-west1 (Belgium) and Firestore in europe-west3 (Frankfurt) and it works pretty well. When the Cloud Function has to interact with Firestore we experiment some extra latency compare to, e.g., a set up in us-central. I didn't do any precise benchmarking but I would say that it rarely goes over 3 extra seconds. Actually I don't know what is taking much time, a cold start or the connection between the CF and Firestore location. If there weren't any GDPR constraints I would have probably chosen a us-central set-up.

Comment: What do you mean by GDPR constraints? I'm saving some user data like id, name permissions in my database, but i will follow GDPR regulations. Why can't have my database in the us-central, can't find anywhere that's written?

Comment: GDPR constraints: this is a broad debate! You can for example read different discussions here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/GDPR%7Csort:date. Even if Firebase (and GCP) storage in the US is GDPR compliant, because of the EU-U.S. Privacy Shield Framework (see https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/) what I experiment is that most of my (Belgium based) customers do prefer to have their data stored in a European location. However, it is to be noted that Firebase Authentication (which may use emails, i.e. personal data) can only be located in the US.